# Get text in next tag after this text - Simple HTML Dom Parser

Tags: html, parsing, dom, simple-html-dom

I am trying to get the value for  First name and surname below using the Simple HTML dom parser. 
Is there a way I can refer to the label and get the next sibling as the order may change.

```
$item['city'] = trim($article->find('label', 0)->plaintext);
```

Code I have started but I don't know how to refer to First Name.

HTML

```
<div class="summary">
    <h3>Listing summary</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label>Reference</label>
            <strong>SP44</strong>
        </li>    
        <li>
            <label>First Name</label>
            <strong>John</strong>
        </li>    
        <li>
            <label>Surname</label>
            <strong>Smith</strong>
        </li>    
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

loop over the list items and check the label of that item against your criteria

```
foreach( $article->find('li') as $li){
    switch($li->find('label',0)->plaintext){
         case 'First Name':
             $item['first_name'] = $li->find('strong', 0)->plaintext;
             break;
         case 'Surname':
             $item['surname'] = $li->find('strong', 0)->plaintext;
             break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is the code which you have posted better/quicker if I have lots of items to retrieve compared to the one I have posted below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I have come up with something similar: 
Does this code use lots of processing power compared to the one above?, Is it a good idea to make this into a function?

```
foreach($html->find('div[class=summary] li') as $e) {
if(strpos($e->find('label', 0), "first Name") > 0 ) {  
echo $e->find('strong', 0). '<br>';
}
if(strpos($e->find('label', 0), "surname") > 0 ) {  
echo $e->find('strong', 0). '<br>';
} }
```